# how to start project with visual nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

i try to use visual nhibernate. I create mappings, entity,.. What now? Until now i was doing like here:

```
http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx
```

but after using visual nhibernate i do not know ehere to start. Is any good tutorial on the net?

Comment: Are you using Visual NHibernate or Fluent NHibernate?  Or are you using Visual NHibernate to generate Fluent NHibernate mappings?  You need to explain your situation a little more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new book has just been published. It looks like it's got a sample project included:
[NHibernate 3 Beginners Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-beginners-guide/book)